# Writing tests as functions in Dalek.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, dalekjs

I've been using Dalek.js for testing and have been enjoying it. I would like to take some tests from one of my files and put them in a separate "common_tests.js" file so that I can use them in other places without having to duplicate code. However, whenever I try moving the test code out of the main file, the test fails to execute correctly -- I get the "RUNNING TEST - '[TEST NAME]'" message twice. The first does nothing, and the second immediately hangs while trying to open the page. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

My code is in this format:

In common_tests.js:

```
module.exports = {
    testFunction: function(test) {
        test
            .open("www.google.com")
            // other testing stuff here that's fine when in the other file
        .done();
}
```

In my tests file:

```
var common = require('../common_tests.js");
module.exports = {
    'Trying to test with functions': function(test) {
        common.testFunction(test);
        test.done();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used DalekJS, but it looks like you are calling `test.done()` twice : once in the shared function you wrote in `common_tests.js`, and then in your test file, after calling the common function.

I would have written the test file like this:

```js
var common = require('../common_tests.js');

module.exports = {
    'Trying to test with functions': common.testFunction,
};
```